# In Swift, can Types (not instances) conform to protocols?

Tags: swift, generics, types, polymorphism

I have a ViewController that uses a class (call it `A`) from a framework outside of my control. `A` provides a class function I need (call it `f`). I want to make `A` easy to mock out in tests.

So my idea was to create a protocol `P` that has the same signature as `A`, extend A to implement P, and then create a mock class `M` that also implements `P` and has a dummy implementation of `f`. Then in my tests, I could just do `viewController.dependency = M` and everything should be dandy.

This is easier said than done, for reasons I'm hoping you'll help me understand.

Inside my viewController, it's easy to declare a variable that contains a protocol-conforming instance and then reassign the variable to another Protocol-conforming instance:

```
// works
var dependency: P = A()
dependency.f()
dependency = M()
dependency.f()
```

But it doesn't work to do the same thing with just the types:

```
// doesn't work
var dependency = A.self
dependency = M.self  // cannot assign value of M.Type to a value of type A.Type

// also doesn't work
var dependency: P = A.self // type A.Type does not conform to protocol P
```

Is there a way to make this work? I thought maybe I could use a generic type for `dependency` but I can't figure out a syntax to declare a generic type for a variable assignment.

Comment: Why isn't `dependency = M()` sufficient for your needs?

Comment: I'd rather avoid instantiating the class because I only ever use class methods on it. Also, Swift won't let you call class methods on instances so `dependency = M(); dependency.f()` won't compile. I could do `dependency = M(); dependency.dynamicType.f()` but that smells bad...and I'd have to replace every existing `dependency.f()` call in my VC code with `dependency.dynamicType.f()` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to store the type itself, you can use `P.Type`. The following works in Swift 2:

```
protocol P {
    static func foo()
}

class A: P {
    static func foo() { print("A foo") }
}
class M: P {
    static func foo() { print("M foo") }
}

var dependency: P.Type = A.self
dependency = M.self

dependency.foo()
```

Comment: Hooray! That looks like just what I want. Sadly it doesn't work in Swift 1.2 because accessing members of Protocol types isn't implemented. But in a few weeks this should work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because when you say `var dependency = A.self`, the compiler infers, from the right-hand side, that `dependency`'s type is `A`. That means that if `dependency` ever gets reassigned, it can be assigned only to some other instance of an `A` class type. When you created protocol `P` with the same signature as `A`, then a a class `M` that implements `P`, you still haven't (and can't, since it's out of your control) made *`A`* implement protocol `P`. The way the Swift and Objective-C runtimes work is that each object contains a pointer to its *type* class. This type is inspected when assigning, and if the right-hand value is being assigned to a left-hand declaration, then the right-hand value has to have the left-hand's type somewhere in its inheritance hierarchy.

Some languages (e.g. Ruby) feature so-called *[duck typing](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/duck_typing.html)*, where if an object or class *walks* like a duck, then it *is* a duck, even if it's not *really* an instance of a duck. That's what you're looking for here, but Swift (and Objective-C) don't work that way. Duck typing is a type of *pseudo-polymorphism*. It's not *really* polymorphic.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I would also extend `A` to implement `P`. I edited the question to clarify that. If A does implement P, the compiler is smart enough to let me re-assign dependency to `M()` (the instance, as in my first example), but not the raw Type `M`.